# In $\triangle ABC$, height $h_a=2m$ and perimeter$=7m$, find maximum height $h_b$.

Tags: geometry, optimization, triangles

In $\triangle ABC$, height $h_a=2m$ and perimeter$=7m$, find maximum height $h_b$ and write the formula used.

Note: Not easy or incomplete question, you don't have angles or any other data.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Heavily related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1279200/the-minimum-perimeter-and-maximum-height-of-a-triangle-under-constraints/1279324#1279324

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach: assume that the projection of $A$ on the $BC$-line splits the $BC$-side in two segments having length $x$ and $y$. We have to fulfill
$$ x+y+\sqrt{x^2+4m^2}+\sqrt{y^2+4m^2} = 7m $$
and we have to maximize $h_b = \frac{2\Delta}{b}=\frac{2m(x+y)}{\sqrt{x^2+4m^2}}$.
 This problem can be tackled through [Lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier). However, it is probably easier to solve the dual problem, i.e. to find the minimum perimeter of a triangle with two given heights $h_a,h_b$.
It is also useful [to recall](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/539300/finding-inradius-given-the-heights) that:
$$ \frac{p}{\Delta} = \frac{1}{h_a}+\frac{1}{h_b}+\frac{1}{h_c}$$
$$ \frac{1}{\Delta}= \sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{h_a}+\frac{1}{h_b}+\frac{1}{h_c}\right)\left(-\frac{1}{h_a}+\frac{1}{h_b}+\frac{1}{h_c}\right)\left(\frac{1}{h_a}-\frac{1}{h_b}+\frac{1}{h_c}\right)\left(\frac{1}{h_a}+\frac{1}{h_b}-\frac{1}{h_c}\right)}$$

This turns out to be quite a difficult problem. Have a look at [this similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1279200/the-minimum-perimeter-and-maximum-height-of-a-triangle-under-constraints/1279324#1279324) (and my answer), too. The optimal $b$ is given by the stationary point of $b+7-\sqrt{b^2-4}$, that occurs at $b\approx 2.03737$.

Comment: \begin{equation}
h_{b} =  \frac{perimeter \cdot \sin(\gamma) \cdot (2h_{a}-perimeter \cdot \sin( \gamma ))}{2 \cdot (h_{a} \cdot \cos(\gamma) - perimeter \cdot \sin(\gamma) + h_{a})}
\end{equation}

Can you help me?
I can not continue.

Comment: @Salvatore: you just have to study the stationary points of such function of $\gamma$, hence you "just" have to compute $\frac{d}{d\gamma}RHS$ and equate it to zero to get the optimal value of $\gamma$, maximizing $h_b$.

Comment: I can not compute what you propose.
You can try it for me?
I'm not very skilled with mathematical software.

Comment: @Salvatore: there is no need of any software to compute $$\frac{d}{d\gamma}\left(\frac{A\sin\gamma+B\sin^2\gamma}{C\sin\gamma+D\cos\gamma+E}\right)$$ !

Comment: With TrianCal online triangles calculator is 2.200997682574073 m